# Apply date parameters ssrs pie charts

Tags: date, reporting-services, powerbi, pie-chart

I have two pie charts in an SSRS report and I need show current values in one chart and previous month values in the other chart. Previous month end can be any month in the last 2 years.

What is the best to set up the report so that one chart shows the most recent month end data by default and the month end date for the other chart is selected using a parameter.  I have data in one dataset for all of the last 2 years and have created 2 date columns in the dataset, one named Current Date and the other Previous Date, each of these columns have been designated as parameters.  I have applied filters to each chart to set the date for that chart to be based on either the current date or previous date parameter selection.

When I generate the report I am getting no results, just blank report.  Perhaps I can't do this from one dataset? Also, if I need to use 2 datasets will I need to set the second pie chart up as a sub-report since only one dataset is allowed per tablix?

```
HHID | Class | HH_Allocation | Recent Date | Previous Date
```

From HH Table There are 4 parameters, 2 from a different table plus Recent Date and Previous from this table. The Recent Date chart and previous date charts are side by side and I attempted to use the filter for each chart and filter them by the date parameters selected when the report is run. The Y value for the pie chart is HH_Allocation, the Category Group for the chart is Class. I thought that I could add the dates a series group for the pie chart but that did not work.

Here are a couple rows of data:

| HHID | Class | HH_Alloc | Recent Date | Previous Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | HH Stock | 10% | 03/31/2023 | 03/31/2023 |
| Smith | HH Stock | 5% | 02/28/2023 | 02/28/2023 |
| Smith | HH Stock | 3% | 01/31/2023 | 01/31/2023 |

In this case if 3/31 was chosen as the recent date, that chart would show a 10% allocation and if 2/28 was selected for the previous date that chart would show a 5% allocation.

Comment: You should be OK with all the data in a single dataset, it's probably your parameters or filtering that are wrong. Can you show a sample of the dataset (as text, not an image) and also explain what is in your parameters.

Comment: HHID |  Class  | HH_Allocation | Recent Date | Previous Date

Comment: HHID |  Class  | HH_Allocation | Recent Date | Previous Date
From HH Table

There are 4 parameters, 2 from a different table plus Recent Date and Previous from this table.  The Recent Date chart and previous date charts are side by side and I attempted to use the filter for each chart and filter them by the date parameters selected when the report is run.  The Y value for the pie chart is HH_Allocation, the Category Group for the chart is Class.  I thought that I could add the dates a series group for the pie chart but that did not work.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here are a couple rows of data:

HHID |            | Class |         | HH_Alloc |         | Recent Date |          | Previous Date |
Smith HH         Stock             10%                      03/31/2023               03/31/2023
Smith HH         Stock                5%                     02/28/2023               02/28/2023

In this case the recent chart would show a 10% allocation and if 2/28 was selected for the previous date that chart would show  a 5% allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info but could you edit your question and add the info there rather than in the comments as it's hard to read. Include enough data so that at least parameter values would give valid results (I think you only included 1 in the above). I'll pick this up tonight if I get chance.

Comment: sorry, typo... should read "enough data so that at least **two** parameter values would give valid results "

Comment: I've edited your updates, hopefully I got the table structure correct. The problem with what you have in your sample is that for any one month, there will only be a single value. and it will always be 100%.m If you want (for 2023-03-31 to show 10%), then you'll have to calculate the remaining portion.  Also, where you have "10%" for example, I assume the actual value is 0.1 ? Finally, the recent and previous dates are always the same, is this correct? I've built a simple solution based on my assumptions, I'll share it once you answer the above so I know if it's correct or not.

Comment: I only put one allocation per month in the example, so consider if there is 10% in stocks there would be 90% in bonds and yes the actual value would be .01.  Yes, the current and previous dates that can be selected will be the same.  With the current date being applied to one chart and the previous date being applied to the other chart.  And ideally the current chart would default to the last month end but I am not concerned about that yet.

Comment: I've added a full answer. Don't worry about the length of it, it's pretty simple, I just like to explain with lots of pictures! :)

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem, please mark it as accepted. This help other users find similar questions that had been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, after reading all the comments, I've taken a slightly different approach. I've left both date columns in but only one is used and there is just a single parameter which allows the user to select the 'previous' month.

First I recreated your sample data, then I generate additional rows to give the remaining %split (e.g. if the allocation was 10% (0.1), then additional matching row would be 90% (0.9). You just need to rename the 'Allocated'/'Unallocated' labels to suit your needs as this is what we show in the chart legend.

I've also added a column which calculates if these rows are from the most recent date so we can filter the first chart based on this.

Here's the full dataset query I used ..

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (HHID varchar (10), Class varchar(20), HH_Alloc decimal (10,6), RecentDate Date, PreviousDate Date)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('Smith', 'HH Stock', 0.10, '2023-03-31', '2023-03-31'),
('Smith', 'HH Stock', 0.05, '2023-02-28', '2023-02-28'),
('Smith', 'HH Stock', 0.03, '2023-01-31', '2023-01-31')

SELECT 
    u.* 
    ,IsRecentMonth =  IIF(RecentDate = MAX(RecentDate) OVER(), 1, 0)
  FROM 
  (
  SELECT 'Allocated' as Split, HHID, Class, HH_Alloc, RecentDate, PreviousDate FROM @t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Unallocated' as Split, HHID, Class, 1- HH_Alloc, RecentDate, PreviousDate FROM @t
  ) u
```

This givers the following results (as mentioned earlier, only one date is now required but I left both in, in case you needed it for something else)

[image]

So, in the report, dataset1 is the query above. I then added another dataset (`prevMonth`) to get a list of selectable dates.

As I'm just using dummy data in a table variable I had to recreate the same sample data but obviously you won't, you can just use the actual data containing the data .

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (HHID varchar (10), Class varchar(20), HH_Alloc decimal (10,6), RecentDate Date, PreviousDate Date)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('Smith', 'HH Stock', 0.10, '2023-03-31', '2023-03-31'), ('Smith', 'HH Stock', 0.05, '2023-02-28', '2023-02-28'), ('Smith', 'HH Stock', 0.03, '2023-01-31', '2023-01-31')

SELECT  DISTINCT PreviousMonth = CAST(PreviousDate as varchar(50)) 
from @t order by PreviousMonth Desc
```

I've converted the dates to string for the parameter values otherwise it would be represented in a date picker which did not sound like what you wanted. This way you'll just get the text representation to pick from.

Next I added a report parameter called `prvMonth` and set the available values to get from a query. Dataset = `prevMonth`; Value Field and Label Field both set to `PreviousMonth`.

Next I added 2 pie charts

First chart is setup like this (this is where we use the additional `IsRecentMonth` column).

[image]

The second chart is the same except for the filter which looks like this.

[image]

That's it. When we run the report, left left chart always shows the most recent data and the right chart shows the data from the select date.

[image]